# Multiple Plugins Interacting with Menu

Tags: plugins, menus, conditional-tags

Got an issue with the use of multiple plugins interacting with the menu system in WordPress.

We are using UberMenu and wanted to use [If Menu](http://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/) as well to control the visibility of some of the menu items. However UberMenu overrides If Menu and it can't be used.

On the UberMenu forum one of the developers said

> Unfortunately it is a limitation of the WordPress menu
>   system that you can only have one plugin/theme adding settings to a
>   menu item at a time.

and mentioned he was working on a work around.

I'm curious has anyone else experienced this issue and could anyone offer a suggestion for a work around.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about WordPress within the scope defined in the help center, as plugin questions are generally off-topic, esp. questions about issues with and modifying plugins. Refer to the plugin author or company.  See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I appreciate your point @songdogtech I understand that being about the plugin is off topic but its more that I am interested in the reasoning behind the limitation of only one plugin being able to interact with the menu system at a time. If this is still invalid question then please do close it.

Comment: markdavidson, other people will weight in to the validity of the question; it's a community here. If the Ubermenu people are working on a workaround, they will know more about the plugin code than anyone here, esp. if it a paid/closed source plugin.